# PHP - Generate on-screen alert when accessing server

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function on my Laravel Controller below that accesses a server to execute a command. I am trying to adjust the exception if the informed IP is wrong and send an alert on the screen that could not be connected because the IP, user or password is wrong.

```
    public function accessServer()
    {

        $ip = '192.168.34.13';
        if ($connection = ssh2_connect($ip, 22)) {
        ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'password');

        $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "df -h");
            echo "OK";

    } else {
            echo "Error";
    }
}
```

The above function returned the following error:

```
ErrorException
ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to 192.168.34.13 on port 22
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the try/catch method

```php
public function accessServer()
{

    $ip = '192.168.34.13';
    try {
        $connection = ssh2_connect($ip, 22);
        ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'password');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "Error";
        return;
    }
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "df -h");
    echo "OK";
}
```